# create empty 1px image

Tags: image, firefox, size, width

I create image tag in HTML

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
alert(img.width)
```

```html
<div width="500">
  <img id="image" width="100%" height="1"></img>
</div>
```

In all browsers img.width will be 500px. But in Firefox it will be 0. But if set the src in image tag it work.

Is it possible to set 1px transparent image without using any files(png, jpg, ...)

Comment: You could use a data url: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/ That's probably the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
alert(img.width)

Thanx to LinuxDisciple I found a solution to the problem
```

```html
<div width="500">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" id="image" width="100%" height="1"></img>
</div>
```